# Marangoni Effect and the Navier-Stokes Equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, navier-stokes

A quite well-known phenomena, oftenly treated in recreational physics, is the [Marangoni Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marangoni_effect). Roughly speaking, we have a flux caused by a gradient of surface tension. You can look up YouTube, and you'll see that there are lots of videos covering experiments that illustrate this effect.

It's not hard to understand the phenomenon intuitively, nor to visualize it. But what about it's mathematical description?

Well, what usually happens in the experiment is that we have a viscous fluid, say, soap, moving towards the region of higher surface tension. So we'll probably use the Navier-Stokes equations and the advection equation, fundamentally.

Summarizing, I'd like to know how to do so.